# Return Inputs to UITextfield with custom inputView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uitextfield, ios4

i created a UITextField and a custom View.
after that i added this custom view as "inputView" to my UITextField.

```
 amountKeyboardViewController *amountKeyboard = [[amountKeyboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"amountKeyboardViewController" bundle:nil];

amountTextField.inputView = amountKeyboard.view;

[amountTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

this works quite fine. but can i fill my "amountTextField" with the input clicked in my custom View (UIButtons)?

thanks for some hints !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your amountTextField controller you need to write the following code in .h file

create property of your textfield

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UiTextField *txt; //whatever your textfield name
```

Now in .m file write the following

```
@synthesize txt;
```

write following statement where you create object of amountKeyboardViewController

```
 amountKeyboardViewController *amountKeyboard = [[amountKeyboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"amountKeyboardViewController" bundle:nil]
 amountKeyboard.objamountTextField = self;
```

Now in amountKeyboardViewController controller write the following code

```
@class amountTextField;       //forward declaration
```

then create object of this class

```
amountTextField *objamountTextField;
```

then create property of

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)amountTextField *objamountTextField;
```

Now on click of button

```
-(IBAction)clickof1
{
    if([amountTextField.text length] <= 0)
        objamountTextField.txt.text = @"1";
    else
        objamountTextField.txt.text=[objamountTextField.txt.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}
```

Comment: i'll give it a try this evening and accept your answer if its working. thanks for your great support. two things: "amountTextField controller" do you mean my view controller where my  amountTextField is setted as an instance variable? `amountKeyboard.objamountTextField = self;` can you give me a quick explanation of that?

Comment: Yes,amountTextField controller mean your view controller where  amountTextField is set.

In amountKeyboardViewController  class you can see that i have create a object of amountTextField and also make a property so we need to set that object

Answer (score 1):

You mean that if you press 1 then '1' should shown in textfield.

after that if you press 2 then it will show '12'.

Do you want like this?

You have to write IBaction for all buttons
eg.

```
-(IBAction)clickof1
{
    if([amountTextField.text length] <= 0)
       amountTextField.text = @"1";
    else
       amountTextField.text = [amountTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}

-(IBAction)clickof2
{
    if([amountTextField.text length] <= 0)
       amountTextField.text = @"2";
    else
       amountTextField.text = [amountTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
}
```

like that you have to write IBaction for all your buttons

Comment: yes i thought of that, but: my actions are in my amountKeyboardViewController and not in my controller where my textfield is created. also what if i want to use this keyboard somewhere else? do i always have to write all my actions for each textfield?

Comment: you need to create property of your textbox and you can access that from amountKeyboardViewController class by using forward declaration and you can set the value

Comment: oh please can you give me a quick sample code about this "forward declaration" in your post above? google stuff looks weird