# iOS - Custom keyboard, updating text field in parent view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, forward-declaration

I am implementing a custom keyboard and need to update the original textField when buttons are touched on that keyboard.

I have tried following the answer to this question:
[Return Inputs to UITextfield with custom inputView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224757/return-inputs-to-uitextfield-with-custom-inputview)
but I don't find it very clear.

In statViewController I have defined my textField `xValue`, and created an instance of my keyboard:

```
DCKeyboard *dckXValue = [[DCKeyboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"DCKeyboard" bundle:nil];
```

The next line of the answer uses self, so I take it that it's suggesting that I should create a property of dckXValue that is a statViewController:

```
dckXValue.objStatViewController = self;
```

Again, I follow the answer through (add the `@class` line, create the object/property) but then in my method that catches my button presses (in DCKeyboard.m), when I reach the line:

```
objStatViewController.xValue.text = @"Some value";
```

I am getting the error "Request for member 'xValue' in something not a structure or union" when I try to compile.

Can anyone give me any hints on where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a problem of property the text field is not a property. Try #import "StatViewController.h" in your implementation file

Comment: Rahul - you were right. I added `#import "StatViewController.h"` to DCKeyboard.m and it's now compiling fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok then I should add my comment as an answer so that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of property the text field is not a property. Try #import "StatViewController.h" in your implementation file